# Ugly text in shaded graphics

Tags: graphics, text, antialiasing

I've looked around but can't find the solution to the following problem: Why is text so ugly in shaded graphics (ContourPlot, etc.)? Here's an illustration:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];
{Histogram[Flatten[data], PlotLabel -> Style["Label 12345", 20]],
 SmoothDensityHistogram[data, PlotLabel -> Style["Label 12345", 20]]}
```

On my system (Mathematica 12.1, Windows 10) I get
[image]

All the text (tick and plot labels) is ugly. I'm not sure if it's low-resolution, aliased, or antialiased the wrong way, but it's just ugly.

Note that in Preferences, I've set Appearance/Graphics/Antialising quality to "highest." I realize that can save the image using a high `ImageResolution` value. But is there any way I can nice-looking text in these kinds of graphics in my notebook?

**Clarification:** what I mean by "ugly" is the text in the right-hand graph. For comparison, the text in the left-hand graph looks much nicer (at least to me).

To make it absolutely clear. Here's the well-formed text (from the left graph):

[image]

and here's the ugly text (from the right graph):

[image]

Do you see the difference?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you mean by "ugly" and what features of the text will make it better?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, andre314: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I mean by "ugly" is the text in the right-hand graph. For comparison, the text in the left-hand graph looks much nicer (at least to me).

Comment: Frankly speaking, I do not see much difference. Do you mean that it is a bit washed out? Gray, rather than black? Maybe, you would like another font? Or size?

Comment: @andre314 "Maybe you could post something that is not ugly, so that we understand what you mean ?" -- Yeah. Voting to close as "opinion based."

Comment: I certainly see the difference in quality between the two labels, but cannot reproduce it. On my system (12.1, MacOS), your code results in two identical, high-quality labels.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2140538).

Comment: One difference between these plots is that the right one has a frame. Do you get the same problem when replacing the ```PlotLabel``` option with ```FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, Style["Label 12345", 20]}}]``` ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this better?

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];
Row[{
  Rasterize[
   Histogram[Flatten[data], 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style["Label 12345", 20, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"]], 
   RasterSize -> 1200, ImageSize -> 300], 
  Rasterize[
   SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style["Label 12345", 20, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"]], 
   RasterSize -> 1200, ImageSize -> 300]
  }]
```

[image]

??

Comment: It's better, but is there a solution that doesn't require me to Rasterize all my plots?

Comment: Why not? You need no Rasterize or an image quality? Just explain clearly what are you after?

Comment: I just want to be able to use functions like `SmoothDensityHistogram` and get nice-looking text labels without having to do anything special, other than setting an option or something.

Comment: I do not see the way to do that. Maybe, somebody else will.